# No release file error

Tags: apt, 22.04, update-manager

I have a VM running ubuntu 22.04 but when I try to do a sudo update, this is the error list:

```
$ sudo apt update -y
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease                                                                                               
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                    
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                         
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                               
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release                                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:10 https://dl.teradici.com/sLc2Y8yo0wbo3LGu/pcoip-agent/deb/ubuntu bionic InRelease [5240 B]                                  
Hit:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                       
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

**Update**

New `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

After running `sudo apt-get update -y`, this is the terminal output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                                                                      
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                   
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                  
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                  
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [11.4 kB]                                                                                         
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                     
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:10 https://dl.teradici.com/sLc2Y8yo0wbo3LGu/pcoip-agent/deb/ubuntu bionic InRelease [5240 B]             
Hit:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                      
Err:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                              
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

**Update 2**

I removed everything in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Now, these are my update outputs:

```
$ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
 sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sources are not valid. Your sources list includes sources for `hirsute` and `xenial`. You also have sources for Debian. None of these sources are appropriate for Ubuntu 22.04 (`jammy`) and should be removed.  Never add sources for another distribution or you risk breaking your system. Only add sources for your distribution, which is Ubuntu 22.04 (`jammy`).

Once you have removed the offending sources, run the following commands to bring your system up-to-date:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: How can I replace these sources with Jammay via SSH?

Comment: check the post edit..

Comment: I did try to remove them but clearly I couldn't do it right.

Comment: @Nmah Check the post again. I've added new updates. Now, I can't update anything..